# select values seperated by Comma using Group By

Tags: sql, t-sql

*I want to select commaa seperated values using Group By.*

**Example:** If i want to list  all states of America seperated by comma and group by country Name which is America.

Comment: please post the table in question and your desired output, and also, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You're going to need to add a little more detail about what software/system you're using. Also showing us what you have already got working so far, and telling us how it differs from what you want would be useful.

Comment: i need exactly the same thing what i posted. i have all the countries in my list and there cities. What i want is show all the cities name in front of country name seperated by commma

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Since you are not sharing more details with us, this is not done using "GROUP BY", but rather abusing the GROUP (which is stackoverflow):

```
America, Alabama
America, Alaska
America, Arizona
America, Arkansas
America, California
America, Colorado
America, Connecticut
America, Delaware
America, Florida
America, Georgia
America, Hawaii
America, Idaho
America, Illinois
America, Indiana
America, Iowa
America, Kansas
America, Kentucky
America, Louisiana
America, Maine
America, Maryland
America, Massachusetts
America, Michigan
America, Minnesota
America, Mississippi
America, Missouri
America, Montana
America, Nebraska
America, Nevada
America, New Hampshire
America, New Jersey
America, New Mexico
America, New York
America, North Carolina
America, North Dakota
America, Ohio
America, Oklahoma
America, Oregon
America, Pennsylvania
America, Rhode Island
America, South Carolina
America, South Dakota
America, Tennessee
America, Texas
America, Utah
America, Vermont
America, Virginia
America, Washington
America, West Virginia
America, Wisconsin
America, Wyoming
```

Comment: Mr. mindandmedia there is no point of not sharing. Understanding a question is part of Question.
i dont need this thing. i mentioned clearly i have this listing and i want is |America | Oregon,West Virginia, all states in this format.|

Comment: just try to provide more input to your original question and the community will help you in a non-sarcastic way... and no, you didn't state anything clearly. maybe state it in your own language, than use google-translator?